# Unable to add-apt-repository for docker on ubuntu disco distribution

Tags: docker, ubuntu-18.04

Trying to add docker repository on ubuntu, but I am getting below error:

```
Ign:1 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:2 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu disco InRelease
Hit:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco InRelease                 
Get:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-updates InRelease [97.5 kB]
Get:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-backports InRelease [88.8 kB]        
Get:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu disco-security InRelease [97.5 kB]         
Err:7 https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu disco Release                                                                                                                           
  Could not wait for server fd - select (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) [IP: 10.166.17.46 3128]
Reading package lists... Done                    
E: The repository 'https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu disco Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
```

Here is the command which I tried:

```
sudo add-apt-repository "deb [arch=amd64] https://download.docker.com/linux/ubuntu disco stable"
```

I also tried with ubuntu 18.04 but getting the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow all steps for repository setup  from docker website https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/ubuntu/ of which your command is only 4th. As an alternative  you may follow manual install path as described on docker website.  Download deb files then `sudo apt install ./*.deb` in folder where you put downloaded deb files.

Answer (score 0):

Why you are not using the [snap store](https://snapcraft.io/)? which contain the [stable version](https://snapcraft.io/search?q=docker)

Snaps are discoverable and installable from the Snap Store, an app store with an audience of millions.

**Enable snapd**

> If you’re running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Xenial Xerus) or later, including
>   Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver), Ubuntu 18.10 (Cosmic Cuttlefish) and
>   Ubuntu 19.04 (Disco Dingo), you don’t need to do anything. Snap is
>   already installed and ready to go.

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd # (only if not snap not installed)
sudo snap install docker
```

Comment: it seems even with snapd I am having trouble, so went ahead with the installation manually.